# Gstreamer Pipeline doesn´t close after livestream has finished

Tags: c#, .net, gstreamer

I´m trying to send a stream from a server to a client using Gstreamer. The server sends the data succesfully and I can hear the file on the client, but the client pipeline doesn't close after the livestream has finished. I'm using the GStreamer core Nuget.

```cs
static Element Pipeline;
static GLib.MainLoop MainLoop;
static bool IsLive = false;
static bool StreamIncoming;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Playing video and audio from me");
    Gst.Application.Init(ref args);
   
    //My Pipeline that reads a file and streams it via RTP
    Pipeline = Gst.Parse.Launch($"filesrc location=/home/pi/a-team_intro.wav ! decodebin ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=8000,channels=1 ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink host=172.16.20.101 port=5800");
            
    MainLoop = new GLib.MainLoop();

    Pipeline.Bus.AddSignalWatch();
    Pipeline.Bus.EnableSyncMessageEmission();
    Pipeline.Bus.Message += OnMessage;
    Pipeline.Bus.SyncMessage += OnSync;
            
    var ret = Pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
    if (ret == StateChangeReturn.Failure)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.");
        return;
    }
    else if (ret == StateChangeReturn.NoPreroll)
    {
        IsLive = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Playing a live stream.");
    }

    MainLoop.Run();

    //tried to send a EOS event manually
    //var eosEvent = Event.NewEos();
    //Pipeline.SendEvent(eosEvent);         

    Pipeline.SetState(State.Null);
    StreamIncoming = false;
```

And the busmessages (especially the EOS-Signal) I handle like this in the OMessage function:

```cs
case MessageType.Eos:
    System.Console.WriteLine("[Eos] Playback has ended. Exiting!");
    MainLoop.Quit();
    break;
```

On the receiver side it is the same with another pipeline that looks like this:

```
"udpsrc port=5800 ! "application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)8000,encoding-name=(string)PCMA" ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtppcmadepay ! alawdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink"
```

I don´t know if the pipeline doesn´t receive an EOS-Signal or it has components that don´t care about an EOS-Signal.